# Thread.CurrentThread.CurrenCulture.LCID gets reset after a WCF connection from a client?

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

Two applications, when both load, they use Application.Run to launch a form, after that form loads they set the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture to a user selected culture in both applications.

I have a named pipe listener in one application and a client connection from the other, when the listener is invoked, the thread culture has been reset to the machine default. The call stack seems to implicate the calling thread is the one which called Application.Run which means a different thread to the one which had it's culture changed.

How do I go about changing the parent thread culture when I change the CurrentThread? I guess that's the way to avoid this?

Setting Application.CurrentCulture still seems to leave the parent thread with Main as the original culture.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the below solved the issue:

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
```